# Full list of font families provided with Flutter?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter we can use TextStyle to provide a desired fontFamily property for the text.
While some fontFamily names are obvious and do work (like 'Arial', 'Courier', 'Times' and so on), where's the full list of available options?

The docs (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/fontFamily.html) don't help.

Comment: Have a look at [typography.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/fe22d196fc004d01d5e8ae618ac34744ad03a6ac/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/typography.dart#L340)

Comment: @easeccy Well it doesn't even mention font families like Courier or Times. Fallback fonts or setting up custom fonts is another topic. My question is about where's the full list of font families that I can specify for Flutter without using anything else and while I see that some "guesses" work, I'd love to see some actual documentation on this.

Comment: `Roboto` on Android, `.SF UI Display` and `.SF UI Text` on iOS. If you want a different font then you should add it manually. Also, try 'google_font' package.

Comment: Those are clearly not the only ones that work out of the box without adding anything, try, for example `fontFamily: 'Courier'` and it will work too, same with some other common font names. The docs don't mention it and I find it strange. There should be some source for this, right?

Answer (score 3):

I recently encountered the same problem with fonts and Flutters incomplete documentation of font list.

A much easier solution for me was to import Google's font library:

```
//Import the font package
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

//Use the Font package instead of TextStyle with your custom tweeks
Text('Sign Up',
    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
        color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 59, 59, 61),
        fontSize: 64,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
    ),
),
```

And the list of fonts offered by this library is HUGE.
check them out with complete examples from here:
https://fonts.google.com/

Answer (score 2):

I do not think such a list is provided by the Flutter team. The fonts you mention are probably system default fonts. Flutter handles the use of custom fonts with a 'Custom Font Fallback'. Listed below is a tool snippet of how this goes to work:

#### Snippet

*In the following example, any glyphs not present in the font `Raleway` will be attempted to be resolved with `Noto Sans CJK SC`, and then with `Noto Color Emoji`:*

```dart
const TextStyle(
    fontFamily: 'RaleWay',
    fontFamilyFallback: <String>[
        'Noto Sans CJK SC',
        'Noto Color Emoji',
    ],
)
```

*If all custom fallback font families are exhausted and no match was found
or no custom fallback was provided, the platform font fallback will be used.*

Since you do not provide any FallBack fonts, Flutter automatically uses the the fonts default to your system of choice.

I hope this you understand what happens now! Please look at the documentation on how to add custom fonts:

[Flutter font documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts)

Comment: Thanks for the input, but setting up a custom font is an easy solution (to a question how to set up a custom font).. I'm just looking for a full list of actual font families that Flutter deemed worthy of having on board. Fallback fonts are one thing, however, here I'm talking about the fact that we can specifically tell Flutter what to use and it will work. So where's the full list of this "what-to-use"?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to tell you, flutter does not have list of fonts they find 'worthy'. If you do not provide a FontFamilyFallBack, flutter retrieves these from the operating of choice (Android or iOS). You can use any font as long as you provide it as an asset in your flutter project. Hence why I redirected you to the custom font documentation.

Comment: Yes, I have absolutely no problems with implementing my own custom fonts. The question is about why exactly things like `fontFamily: 'Courier'` work in Flutter out of the box (without adding custom font) and where is the full list of such options? I don't think that it's a fallback to some system default (which would be, say, Roboto for Android) Courier sure looks like Courier and Times has all the right features and so on. If you try something like `fontFamily: 'Lucida'` - then you will see system default.

Comment: Things like `fontFamily: 'Courier` work because flutter uses a FontFallBack. These fallback fonts are retrieved from the operating system. If you want a list of all the fonts that work 'out of the box', you should look into the supported fonts of your desired operating system.

Answer (score 1):

You don´t need to worry about the default fonts.
You can download a font that you like from here https://fonts.google.com/

Then add it to your assets folder, and update your pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  fonts:
    - family: yourFont
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/yourFont.ttf
    - family: otherFont
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/otherFont.ttf
```

[image]

After that, you can use it like this:

```
Text('Some text',
     style: TextStyle(
     color: Colors.blue,
     fontFamily: 'yourFont',
     fontSize: 22.0,
     ),
 ),
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm well aware of that. My question was about the stuff that is "built-in", so we can avoid bundling other fonts with the app. So far - no obvious/clear answer with a list of fonts been given. List could be anything, maybe it could just name all available system fonts per-version of iOS/Android or w/e, but there's none. Frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a coda to this rather frustrating thread of answers to a different question than the one being asked...

It turns out that even **Courier** isn't available on Flutter Web (on Chrome, using the CanvasKit renderer, circa March 2023), so I had to embed frickin' `LiberationMono` for a silly debug window if I wanted the columns to line up.

I guess the Flutter team really, really wants everyone to embed every font they might potentially ever use.